# Spring boot with oauth2 authorization code and custom login page

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm not very experienced with Spring and Spring Boot, so that's probably a noob question. I'm trying to make a simple page with user management and a separate oauth2 server (authorization code only) with login page. Can you help me with that?

I saw https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2 but it seems overcomplicated and doesn't use spring boot which seems to make things easier.

I also saw https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/vanilla and other projects there. Unfortunately it seems to be created with API protection in mind (@RestController) and there's no login page option.

Do you know any examples?

My current code looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@Controller
public class AuthServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public String create(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> map) {
        return "OK";
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
            security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600)
            .and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value")
            .and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .secret("secret");
        // @formatter:on
        }

    }

}
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String create(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> map) {
    return "OK";
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600)
        .and()
            .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value")
        .and()
            .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .secret("secret");
    // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

}

Comment: OK, I just found a best simple example of what I've been looking for: https://github.com/dynamind/spring-boot-security-oauth2-minimal

Comment: Incase someone came here looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57557022/1581226)