# Authorization_code grant redirection issue

Tags: apache, spring-boot, proxy, wildfly, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented **authorization_code** grant flow which works fine when my Auth Server is run locally.

- A client is getting **redirected to auth server login page** through
  `/oauth/authorize` end point.
- On **successful login** it is getting redirected to the `redirect_uri` provided in the `/oauth/authorize` call where it is getting the `authorization_code`.

Very well.

The problem is ***when the Auth Server is put behind proxy*** the last step where after successful login client is *supposed* to get the `authorization_code` on redirected resource is not working at all. It is always getting redirected to Auth Server's *root*.

To handle this I created a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` where I configured AuthenticationSuccessHandler as below

```
@Bean
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler savedSuccessHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    savedSuccessHandler.setUseReferer(true);
    return savedSuccessHandler;
}

@Bean
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception
{
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();

    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());

    return usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
}
```

I also did some configurations at proxy level as suggested here.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName my.domain.com
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

And adding below to my application.properties

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

But none of the above worked. I tried some other options as well but I guess they are not worth mentioning here.

I can't figure out if something is getting missed or some misconfiguration.

**Update:** On successful login redirection is not happening to `/ouath/authorize` itself but in case of login failure it is getting redirected to login page with `/login?error`

Also, it is running locally on **Tomcat** but on **Wildfly** behind proxy. I debugged it and found that there is a library in Tomcat : `org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor` which maintains a `RequestInfo` object holding the original `/oauth/authorize` request with all the parameters. When debugged over Wildfly no such object could be found. I am sharing the below for reference. I guess now it is more related to server than proxy.

**Debugging on tomcat**
[image: Debugging on tomcat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the original problem still remaining a mystery I got the implementation finally working (not a proper solution though). Below is the complete setup

- I tried packaging and running application as a jar but then faced issues with loading JSPs. For this some solutions suggested to place all the JSPs under `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp` folder. But in my case I couldn't get it working.
  As a solution instead of packaging the application as a jar I packaged it as a **WAR** with JSPs in their default and ran it as a **jar** with embedded **Apache Tomcat
  versioned 8.5.27 (Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE)**
- For running JSPs over Tomcat below was added in the pom file

**Note :** Some solutions I came across suggested `<scope>` to be valued `provided`. In my case it worked without it. Explicitly mentioning it as commented below.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```

I hope this is helpful in case someone stumbles upon the same problem. Any answers/comments are welcome.